# Uses for C# generics besides collections

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I read on MSDN that generics are useful for creating collections. I am pretty new to C# and I am wondering if there are cases of when you would use generics for purposes other than collections. If there is could you provide an example to illustrate your argument.

Comment: The question and the title seem to be the opposite of one another.  Are you asking about non-collection generics or about non-generic collections?

Comment: Disagree with the close votes, especially unilateral close. This question, while worded poorly and ambiguously as [pointed out by David](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197105/c-sharp-uses-for-generics-besides-collections#comment26668157_18197105), can be read as asking about using generics but not with collections. The title indicates what the *intended* meaning of the ambiguous sentence should be read as: using generics *not* with collections. The linked question is about using collections that are not generic. These are *totally* different things.

Comment: @David I was wondering about non-collection generics.

Comment: Linq? RX? `Task<T>`, Tuple? The list goes on...

Comment: Also keep in mind that generics don't apply just to types, but also algorithms/functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics is a feature whose major aims are to promote code reuse and type safety, which are concepts applicable to a much broader segment of code than just collections.

It is easy to see that code reuse and type safety go easily hand-in-hand with collections: LINQ uses generics to provide algorithms that can operate on any type of enumerable sequence (code reuse) and the various generic collection classes also use generic type information to provide type safety (e.g. a program trying to add an `int` to a `List<string>` will not even compile).

That said, there are many more opportunities to leverage generics. For example, a factory can use generics for type safety:

```
class Factory
{
    // can create any type of Widget, will not allow e.g. Create<string>()
    public Widget Create<T>() where T: Widget { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's just a few out of the .NET libraries:

`IComparer<T>` - interface used to compare two `T`s

`IEquatable<T>` - interface used to determine if two `T`s are equal

`Nullable<T>` - used to provide a null value for non-nullable types (e.g. `int`)

`Tuple<T1, T2>` - used as a quick container that holds two strongly-typed values

`Action<T>` - used to hold a delegate that returns a `T`

Comment: Okay, this helps quite a bit. I figured there had to be more flexibility to generics other than just collections. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A short list of uses for generics (from my own Windows Application Framework):

- Data Access (using Entity Framework and `Repository<T>` pattern)
- Decoupled architecture (using MEF's `GetExport<T>`)
- Caching (using MemoryCache) - even this one is mostly related to collections.
- Generic basic CRUD Contracts (via the `IService<T>` interface which provides basic CRUD methods)
- Graph (Entity Tree) iteration and manipulation.
- [Strongly Typed INotifyPropertyChanged](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/implementing)
- Generic layers all over, from database to ViewModel.
- [`DelegateCommand<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg431410%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) / Messenger
- Expression-based Search criteria for Lists
- [DataTemplateManager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way)

And the list goes on and on forever...

Bottom Line:

Generics is one of the best and more ubiquitous features of C#.